# Adding a non breaking space to a php email does not insert spaces

Tags: php, html, email, space

I have this PHP code:

```
mail($email, $subject, 
  "Welcome to **!\n\n The password for your account is:\n $password", 
  $headers);
```

Adding &nbsp to the php email content does not insert spaces.

I want to put two spaces between the colon and `$password`.  Is there a way to add spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send the email as HTML which requires extra headers and actual HTML in your message body:

```
// Add extra headers to $headers
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

// Send mail as HTML
mail($email, $subject, 
  "<html><body>Welcome to **!<br><br> The password for your account is:<br> &nbsp;$password</body></html>", 
  $headers);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `<html>` and `</html>`: to indicate the message is HTML formatted. Then you can use `&nbsp;`

Use the nl2br function to convert newlines to `<br/>`s.

Also set the Content-Type by appending a header "`Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`".

If you don't want to use HTML: you can use the tab-character `\t` too, but not sure if Hotmail supports that eighter.

Comment: After that you'll have to convert all those `\n`'s to `<br/>`'s

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on what you are reading it in.  The problem with Hotmail is that it sees it as plan text, but converts it to HTML most likely to display to you.

Look at [example 4 on how to send html email using php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

Answer (score 0):

If the e-mail's `Content-Type` is `text/plain`, then all spaces should be honored. Sounds like you're transmitting the e-mail message as `text/html`, which is why you would need the &nbsp to get the second space to show up.

Answer (score 0):

Use the http://swiftmailer.org/ Class to do emailing with PHP. It's nice done and gives you a lot of nice features.

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'wordwrap' when sending the message, this should break up the email and 
fix the issue:

```
@mail($to, $subject, wordwrap($message), $headers);
```